# GraphQL query ( Apollo client link state ) returns empty object {}

Tags: graphql, axios, apollo, react-apollo

The Query

```
const GET_MEMBER = gql`
  query getMembers {
    getMembers @client {
      firstname
      lastname
      __typename
    }
  }
`
export { GET_MEMBER }
```

The Resolver:

```
export default {
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      getMembers: async (_, variables, { cache }) => {
        try {
          const res = await apiClient.get('/contacts')
          return { ...res.data, __typename: 'Member' }
        } catch (e) {
          throw e
        }
      },
    },
```

apiClient is an instance of axios

React App:

```
<Query query={GET_MEMBER}>
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {....
```

I am getting this warning

[image]

and the Query in my React App returns {}

Where should I start to debeg it?

Comment: In your schema you have likely defined something like getMembers: [Members], because of this definition you do not necessarily have to pass back the __typename. I would suggest logging out your res.data to make sure you actually do have information from it. As well as making sure your response from /contacts is returning properties that matched to your defined types in your schema.

Comment: I would stop passing __typename in your resolver because the type in your error is Contact and in your resolver it is Member, and as long as your res.data is mapped to your schema with the expected property names it will pass back that information

Comment: @Benjamin Charais, I think I don't have schema! res.data has the information in 'hydra:member'